# Docker commit omits user-specific ssh-keys

Tags: docker, ssh-keys

I have configured a docker image based on Ubuntu, along with user X.
As soon as i docker commit the configured image & run a new container based on that, i notice that user X ssh-keys are not there.
Steps to reproduce:

```
  1. Raise a docker img (IMG_A), create user X.
  2. su X
  3. ssh-keygen -t ed25519 (creates .ssh directory & priv/public keys)
  4. exit the docker container
  5. docker commit base_img IMG_A
  6. raise a new docker container with base_img
  entering the new docker container, shows that .ssh for user X does not exist
```

Is there a workaround or am i missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `docker commit` is basically never a best practice.  It's not clear from what you're writing where ssh keys might come from, or why you want to publish them in an image; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  (Using a Dockerfile and `docker build` will be much easier to describe here and be much more reproducible in the long term.)

Comment: hello, i am aware of that docker commit is not a good practice; however this meets my needs at the moment.
Thank you for your comment, updated with steps-to-reproduce.